# A simple draggable DIV using jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to make the div `innerDropzone` draggable for below code:

```css
 div.example {
   width: 560px;
   height: 750px;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   color: black;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 40px;
 }
 #dropzone {
   height: 530px;
   width: 530px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 2px dashed #0687FF;
   display: block;
   background-image: url(/Images/RE/02.png);
 }
 #imgzone {
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   overflow: auto;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 2px groove #0687FF;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="example">
  <div id="dropzone" style="text-align: center; float: left">
    <div id="innerDropzone" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 30px; width: 250px; height: 250px">
      <img style="display: none;" id="img" src="nothing" />
    </div>
    <div id="hint" style="position: absolute; top: 22%; left: 30%;">Drop in images from your desktop</div>
  </div>
  <div id="imgzone">
    <div id="imagelist">
      <img id="sampleImg" src="/Images/RE/02.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin: 10px;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to make the DIV draggable as below however it failed:

```
$('#innerDropzone').draggable();
```

Comment: Can you add in jsfiddle?

Comment: Define "failed" for us. Are you getting errors in your browser's console (press F12)? Are there no errors but nothing is happening with the element? Is something happening but it's not what you want/expected (if so, explain what it is you do want/expect)?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist:  there are no errors but nothing is happening with the element

Comment: are you including jquery-ui.js ??? as draggable() is provided by jQuery-UI

Comment: seems to be you want to make it dropable instead

Comment: Please see my updated question. I did included all the necessary JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jquery-ui version 1.8.23 is not compatible with jquery 1.9.1. (as per what i experience)

However as i found [on this **Wiki link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Release_history) Jquery-ui 1.8.23 is compatible with Jquery 1.3.2+.

I test your html with latest libraries, everything is working fine..[here is **fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ccw8gd9/)

So it is Jquery UI and Jquery library compatibility issue. Use latest or compatible libraries.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to make a div draggable, please try following my script in jQuery, working also on touch devices.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
var $canvas = $('#canvas'),
    canvT = $canvas.offset().top,
    canvL = $canvas.offset().left,
    $elem = $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'ball'
    }),
    offL = 0,
    offT = 0,
    dragging = 0,
    touchDev = 0;
var onDrop = function onDrop(e) {
  $(document).off('mousemove.dp');
  $(document).off('mouseup.dp');
  dragging = 0;
};
var onDrag = function onDrag(e) {
  $elem.css({
    'left': e.pageX - canvL + offL,
    'top': e.pageY - canvT + offT
  });
};
$elem.appendTo($canvas);
if ('touchstart' in window) {
  touchDev = 1;
}
//touchDev = 1;
if (touchDev === 0) {
  console.log('mousedown');
  $elem.on('mousedown', function (e) {
    if (dragging === 0) {
      offL = $(this).offset().left - e.pageX;
      offT = $(this).offset().top - e.pageY;
    }
    dragging = 1;
    $(document).on('mousemove.dp', onDrag);
    $(document).on('mouseup.dp', onDrop);
  });
} else {
  $elem.on('touchstart', function(event) {
    var e = event.originalEvent;
    var touch = e.targetTouches[0];
    offL = $(this).offset().left - touch.pageX;
    offT = $(this).offset().top - touch.pageY;
  });
  $elem.on('touchmove', function(event) {
    var e = event.originalEvent,
        touch;
    if (e.targetTouches.length == 1) {
      touch = e.targetTouches[0];
      onDrag(touch);
    }
  });
}
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

JS Bin
http://output.jsbin.com/joweca/

Answer (score 0):

see this site http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ it has a guide to do what you are trying to do. Also ensure in your example you are referencing the jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img style="display: none;" id="img" src="nothing"/>
```

How you'll able to see element when image inside has display none, give it style like

```
#innerDropzone { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; border:1px solid #000; }
```

It's draggable, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjKch/2/)

Comment: This is actually combining with a drag and drop function and the display will change to block when user drop an image into the area.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look example on this website, it show pretty simple code to use jquery drag and drop.
http://www.overpie.com/jquery/articles/jquery-drag-and-drop-example

Answer (score 0):

I thing nothing big wrong in your code. Seeming that your are using JQuery `$('#innerDropzone').draggable();` in head tag. 
Just wrap it in function like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#innerDropzone').draggable();
});
```